# How to make a 'outer' JSON key for JSON object with python

Tags: python, json

I would like to make the following **JSON syntax output with python:**

```
data={
    "timestamp": "1462868427",
    "sites": [
    {
        "name": "SiteA",
        "zone": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "SiteB",
        "zone": 7
    }
    ]
}
```

But I **cannot manage** to get the **'outer' data key** there.

So far I got this output **without the data key:**

```
{
    "timestamp": "1462868427",
    "sites": [
    {
        "name": "SiteA",
        "zone": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "SiteB",
        "zone": 7
    }
    ]
}
```

I have tried with this python code:

```
sites = [
            {
                "name":"nameA",
                "zone":123
            },
            {
                "name":"nameB",
                "zone":324
            }
        ]


        data = {
            "timestamp": 123456567,
            "sites": sites
        }


        print(json.dumps(data, indent = 4))
```

But how do I manage to **get the outer 'data' key there?**

Comment: json doesn't have `=`, it's all `key:value`

Comment: Do you really want `data=`? This is not valid JSON.

Comment: Are you perhaps trying to return a response as JSONP or such? What you're trying to achieve is not JSON.

Comment: I see your point, this explains a lot. Then it will be just a string concatenated, right?

Answer (score 3):

Once you have your data ready, you can simply do this :

```
data = {'data': data}
```

Answer (score 1):

JSON doesn't have `=`, it's all `key:value`.

What you're looking for is

```
data = {
    "data": {
        "timestamp": 123456567,
        "sites": sites
    }
}
json.dumps(data)
```

json.dumps() doesn't care for the name you give to the data object in python. You have to specify it manually inside the object, as a string.

Comment: To add to this since it seems to be a point of confusion for beginners - In general, no object knows what names it's been given as a variable, and no function knows the names of an object either.

Comment: They are however, iirc, stored in `globals()` and `locals()`, but avoid using those